# Additive function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ that is not continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ an additive function, i.e. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$. In particular $f(0)=0$. I had as an exercise that if $f$ is continuous at one point, then $f(x)=xf(1)$, i.e.  it's linear and continuous everywhere. Now, are they additive function that are nowhere continuous ? If yes, could someone provide an example ? I tried by contradiction : i.e. there is $x_n\to 0$ s.t. $f(x_n)\to \pm\infty $. Suppose WLOG $f(x_n)\to +\infty $. Then, for all $m$, there is $n_m$ s.t. $f(x_{n_m})>m$. Now, $$f(x_{n_m})+f(x_{n_{m+1}})=f(x_{n_m})+f(x_{n_{m+1}})>2m+1,$$
but I don't get any contradiction.

Comment: you might want to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation, there is also lots to read at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation